# Unable to create feature table on databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks-community-edition, feature-store

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from datetime import date

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

tempDf = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(date=date(2022,1,22), average=40.12),
    Row(date=date(2022,1,23), average=41.32),
    Row(date=date(2022,1,24), average=44.23),
    Row(date=date(2022,1,26), average=45.34),
    Row(date=date(2022,2,7), average=32.56),
    Row(date=date(2022,2,10), average=43.78),
    Row(date=date(2022,2,12), average=37.89)
])

%sql CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS feature_store

from databricks import feature_store
fs = feature_store.FeatureStoreClient()

fs.create_feature_table(
    name="feature_store.uk_avg_temperature_feature",
    keys=["date"],
    features_df=tempDf,
    description="UK Temperature Features"
)
```

Getting the following error while trying to create feature table -

```
2022/03/04 12:02:40 ERROR databricks.feature_store.utils.rest_utils: 
API request to https://community.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/feature-store/feature-tables/get 
failed with code 503 != 200, retrying up to 2 more times. 
API response body: 
{"error_code":"TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE","message":"The service at /api/2.0/feature-store/feature-tables/get is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."}
```

Note - I'm using databricks community edition.

Comment: maybe system doesn't work and simply you have to wait few hours. Code `503` means internal mistake (ie. on normal web pages `503` could means problems with database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think databricks community edition can't handle Feature Store functionality. It doesn't even have the icon/feature in the side menu.

Let me know if you found a workaround!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).